How to disable keyboard pan/adjusting on a ModalBottomSheet
I have a form with multiple Composable TextFields in a ModalBottomSheet.  The problem is my ModalBottomSheet keeps moving to a partially collapsed state when it should simply stay expanded.  I want to manage the ModalBottomSheet expansion state myself completely.
I have tried setting the window settings to android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateAlwaysHidden" both in my AndroidManifest & also as in my Activity above my setContent.
I have also tried removing all focus requests and handling the focus in ModalBottomSheet, and calling a sheetstate.expand() it on any focus change.
However the problem persists.  Does anyone have any advice?
My code is too complicated to post here and I don't want to post company IP here; but I can share snippets when requested.

Please include a minimal reproducible code sample / snippet / demo of what you currently have.
